# How is a fault location detected in a power system?

Tags: transmission-line, fault

Electrical transmission lines can face various types of short-circuit faults, for example, line-to-ground, line-to-line, etc. How do power system engineers find the fault location by observing from the power station?

Comment: Probably by finding the upstream fuse that blew.

Comment: [A Brief History of Fault Location in Transmission Lines](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9040065)

Comment: Or reflectometry ... sending "high-speed pulse" into the line ... when the default is in the line ...